# How to set schedule time for auto start and stop the instance in AWS EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I tried to schedule the EC2 instance using auto scaling group and Data pipeline but if i give the end time in schedule means it terminate that instance and create instance automatically by itself with new hostdns-ip. There is any option to schedule EC2 instance for start and stop at schedule time

Answer (score 1):

The above use case can be achieved very easily using AWS Lambda Function. Here is a detailed guide of achieving the same.

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/start-stop-lambda-cloudwatch/